# Usestate does not work in Text Label and gives me the same value React native hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, calendar, momentjs, use-state

I have made a week calendar that shows from Sunday-Saturday. The problem is that the text Value does not change eventhough it changes in console.log. I have tried using state and setState but did not worked!Any idea what is the problem?

```
const TextScreen =()=> {
     let [Sunday_formatted, nextSunday] =useState()
     let [Saturday_formatted, nextSaturday]=useState()
    
       const getWeek = (date = new Date()) => {
        const dayIndex = date.getDay();
        const diffToLastSunday = (dayIndex !== 0) ? dayIndex -0 : 6;
        const dateOfSunday = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() - diffToLastSunday));
        const dateOfSaturday = new Date(date.setDate(dateOfSunday.getDate() + 6));
        
        return [dateOfSunday, dateOfSaturday];
      }
      
       let [Sunday, Saturday] = getWeek();
       console.log(Sunday,Saturday)
        
          console.log("First/Last of week as Date Objects: ", Sunday, Saturday);
         Sunday_formatted = moment(Sunday).format("DD");
           Saturday_formatted = moment(Saturday).format("DD.MMMM");
          console.log(Sunday_formatted, "-", Saturday_formatted);
        
        function changeData(){
              Sunday=moment(Sunday).add(7, 'days')
              Saturday=moment(Saturday).add(7,'days')
             nextSunday( moment(Sunday).format("DD"))
               nextSaturday(moment(Saturday).format("DD.MMMM"))
               console.log(nextSunday, '-', nextSaturday)
               console.log('this is the new Sunday', Sunday_formatted)
        }
           
           
        return(
           
       <View backgroundColor='#16DCD3'>     
           
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignContent:'center', padding:20, alignItems:'center'}}>
          <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-back" size={30} color="grey" />
          <Text  style={styles.content} >{Sunday_formatted}-{Saturday_formatted}</Text>
          <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-forward" size={30} color="grey" onPress={()=>changeData()} />        
        </View>
        
       </View>
        
        )
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `const` for `useState` because it stays the same in your code. And it's really bad idea to do things like this

```
Sunday_formatted = moment(Sunday).format("DD");
```

I managed to run next code

```
const TextScreen = () => {
   const [Sunday_formatted, nextSunday] = useState();
   const [Saturday_formatted, nextSaturday] = useState();
    
   const getWeek = (date = new Date()) => {
        const dayIndex = date.getDay();
        const diffToLastSunday = (dayIndex !== 0) ? dayIndex - 0 : 6;
        const dateOfSunday = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() - diffToLastSunday));
        const dateOfSaturday = new Date(date.setDate(dateOfSunday.getDate() + 6));
        
        return [dateOfSunday, dateOfSaturday];
    }
      
    let [Sunday, Saturday] = getWeek();
    console.log(Sunday,Saturday)
        
    function changeData(){
        Sunday=moment(Sunday).add(7, 'days')
        Saturday=moment(Saturday).add(7,'days')
        nextSunday( moment(Sunday).format("DD"))
        nextSaturday(moment(Saturday).format("DD.MMMM"))
        console.log(nextSunday, '-', nextSaturday)
        console.log('this is the new Sunday', Sunday_formatted)
    }
           
           
    return(
        <View backgroundColor='#16DCD3'>     
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignContent:'center', padding:20, alignItems:'center'}}>
                <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-back" size={30} color="grey" />
                <Text  style={styles.content} >{Sunday_formatted}-{Saturday_formatted}</Text>
                <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-forward" size={30} color="grey" onPress={()=>changeData()} />        
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

And also keep in mind that `let [Sunday, Saturday] = getWeek();` runs on every refresh. If you wanna to run it once in initial load wrap it up with `useEffect` without dependencies and assign to formatted data.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const [Sunday, Saturday] = getWeek();

    nextSunday(moment(Sunday).add(7, 'days').format('DD'));
    nextSaturday(moment(Saturday).add(7, 'days').format('DD.MMMM'));
}, []);

function changeData () {
    nextSunday(moment(Sunday_formatted).add(7, 'days').format('DD'));
    nextSaturday(moment(Saturday_formatted).add(7, 'days').format('DD.MMMM'));
}
```

You got `useState` wrong. It's like

```
const [stateProperty, setStateProperty] = useState();
```

in your case `Sunday_formatted` is state property (value) and `nextSunday` is method to change `Sunday_formatted` (setter function)

Comment: Thanks for the advices! I tried the code it runs but instead of let [Sunday, Saturday] = getWeek(); should be const [Sunday, Saturday] = getWeek(); and it runs perfect. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Well one issue is that you are holding the state of Sunday in both Sunday and Sunday_formatted which can cause issues.

```
const TextScreen = () => {
  const getSunday = (date) => {
    const dayIndex = date.getDay();
    const diffToLastSunday = (dayIndex !== 0) ? dayIndex : 6;
    return new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() - diffToLastSunday));
  }

  const getSaturday = (sunday) => {
    return moment(sunday).add(6, 'days').toDate();
  }

  const [Sunday, setSunday] = useState(getSunday(new Date()));
  const [Saturday, setSaturday] = useState(getSaturday(Sunday));

  function changeData() {
    setSunday(moment(Sunday).add(7, 'days').toDate());
    setSaturday(moment(Saturday).add(7, 'days').toDate());
  }

  return (
    <View backgroundColor='#16DCD3'>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignContent: 'center', padding: 20, alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-back" size={30} color="grey" />
        <Text>{moment(Sunday).format("DD")}-{moment(Saturday).format("DD.MMMM")}</Text>
        <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-forward" size={30} color="grey" onClick={() => changeData()} />
      </View>
    </View>
  )

}
```

This way the state for Sunday is in only one place. If you want to use that specfic formatting for Sunday and Saturday in multiple places just extract the formatting into a method and reuse it where needed.